# Node, Express 3: Track last user visit when req.session loaded from cookieSession

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I'm using NodeJS and Express 3. To "permanently" remember the user's login I'm setting a non-expiring cookie like this...

```
app.configure(function(){
        ..
        app.use(express.cookieSession({cookie:{path:'/',httpOnly:true,maxAge:null},secret:'mysecrettt'}));

});
```

This works fine, and the `req.session` is automatically created when the user returns.

However, I'd like to detect the date/time when the user does return the track their last visit. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just store the last visit in the session:

```
app.all('*', function findLastVisit(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.visited)
    req.lastVisit = req.session.visited;

  req.session.visited = Date.now();

  next();
});
```

This will retrieve the previous last visit and store the current date (that will be the next last visit). You can decide when you consider that the user starts a new visit (not necessarily on all routes like in my example).

Hope that helps